# Binary Search Query：Finding midian entry in two sorted arrays

Tags: java, arrays, binary

There are two sorted arrays nums1 and nums2 of size m and n respectively.
Find the median of the two sorted arrays. The overall run time complexity should be O(log (m+n)).

Example 1:
nums1 = [1, 3]
nums2 = [2]

The median is 2.0

Example 2:
nums1 = [1, 2]
nums2 = [3, 4]

The median is (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5

```
public class Solution {
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    // Deal with invalid corner case. 
    if (nums1 == null || nums2 == null || nums1.length == 0 || nums2.length == 0) return 0.0;

    int m = nums1.length, n = nums2.length;
    int l = (m + n + 1) / 2; //left half of the combined median
    int r = (m + n + 2) / 2; //right half of the combined median

    // If the nums1.length + nums2.length is odd, the 2 function will return the same number
    // Else if nums1.length + nums2.length is even, the 2 function will return the left number and right number that make up a median
    return (getKth(nums1, 0, nums2, 0, l) + getKth(nums1, 0, nums2, 0, r)) / 2.0;
}

private double getKth(int[] nums1, int start1, int[] nums2, int start2, int k) {
    // This function finds the Kth element in nums1 + nums2

    // If nums1 is exhausted, return kth number in nums2
    if (start1 > nums1.length - 1) return nums2[start2 + k - 1];

    // If nums2 is exhausted, return kth number in nums1
    if (start2 > nums2.length - 1) return nums1[start1 + k - 1];

    // If k == 1, return the first number
    // Since nums1 and nums2 is sorted, the smaller one among the start point of nums1 and nums2 is the first one
    if (k == 1) return Math.min(nums1[start1], nums2[start2]);

    int mid1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int mid2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (start1 + k / 2 - 1 < nums1.length) mid1 = nums1[start1 + k / 2 - 1];
    if (start2 + k / 2 - 1 < nums2.length) mid2 = nums2[start2 + k / 2 - 1];

    // Throw away half of the array from nums1 or nums2. And cut k in half
    if (mid1 < mid2) {
        return getKth(nums1, start1 + k / 2, nums2, start2, k - k / 2); //nums1.right + nums2
    } else {
        return getKth(nums1, start1, nums2, start2 + k / 2, k - k / 2); //nums1 + nums2.right
    }
}
```

I've understand the reason why get rid of k/2 of one array.if aMid is smaller than bMid,then the max index of aMid in the mixed array is k-1,because at most k/2-1 nums in B will insert into the place before aMid when mix them,as k/2th element in B is larger than aMid.

Please explain why k-k/2 in next iteration, since in the 1st iteration you remove k/2 entries impossible to be the kth entry in the merged array.

For example

0 to k/2-1 entries in the A removed because aMid is smaller than bMid ,meaning aMid at most to be the (k-1)th entry. However, in the B array there's still k/2 entries which can't be ruled out. In next iteration function getkth(A, aStart + k/2, B, bStart, k - k/2) bMid=B[0+k/4-1],aMid=A[3k/4-1].How about the left B[k/4 to k/2] entries?

there's no reason to rule them out.what is the iteration mechanism of this algorithm?

Comment: Hi ifchan! If you are going to add questions or clarification please [edit] your question instead of adding it in the comments (It's harder to find if it's in the comments)

Comment: @GBlodgett,you can now see my question